# How to redirect all paths except two if a condition is not met in Express

Tags: express, nodejs-server

On my express server I'am tring to implement the following logic:

1. If the path is not /Login or /Register
2. And the request.session.authenticated is not true.
3. Redirect all request to /Login.

In other words , pseudocode :

```
function()
    {
        if (req.session.authenticated !== true && path !== '/Login')
            res.redirect('/Login')
    }
```

How can i write this function in Express with app.get() or similar ?

```
app.get( path , (req, res) => 
{
  // ??
})
```

------------------------------------------- After edited --------------------------

So  , I tried this :

```
app.use(redirect())

function redirect(req, res, next) 
{
  if (req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Login/Login.html' || req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Register/Register.html') 
    {
      res.redirect('/Login/Login.html');
      return next()
    }
}
```

But , I got the following error :

```
  if (req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Login/Login.html' || req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Register/Register.html')
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
```

I guess that for some reason this function does not have acess to the request object which is weird. How can I make it acess the request ? I thought all middleware functions would have acess to the request.

------------------------------------2nd Edit------------------------------------

In my case the middleware function above only works if you save it to a variable and then use app.use() calling the variable the function was saved in.

So that would be :

```
app.use(redirectMe)

let redirectMe = function redirect(req, res, next) 
{
  if (req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Login/Login.html' || req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Register/Register.html') 
    {
      res.redirect('/Login/Login.html');
      return next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like an authentication middleware for this.

```
function redirect(req, res, next) {
        if (req.session.authenticated !== true && req.path !== '/Login' && req.path !== '/Register') {
            res.redirect('/Login');
            return
        }
    }
```

And the you just need to export that function and you can use it as a middleware in your routes. Something like this:

```
app.get('/profile', redirect(), (req, res) => {
  //Some code here
});
```

Comment: If I do something like app.use(redirect()) , would the server run that function for every HTTP request that comes in ?

Comment: Yes it will work like this, I think it should be without () but you can try both ways. And if there is a problem with this usage instead of return you can write **next()**

Comment: Take a look at my edit  , for some reason I do not have acess to the request.

Comment: Have you tried using it this way: app.use(redirect)

Comment: yes , but it does nto work because if I do that it doesn't call the fuction.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function in a golobal variable as shown below

```
let verifyLogin = (req, res,next){ 
        if(req.session.authenticated)
        { 
          next()
        } else {
          res.redirect('/login')
        }
    }
```

The above function is called from app.get() as shown below

```
 app.get('path', verifyLogin, (req, res)=>{
             //
    })
```